# how to use jquery's semantic tabs without the div switching functionality?

Tags: jquery, tabs, semantics

I need to have the tabs as rendered by jQuery's semantic tabs (semtabs) but without the functionality that shows one div and hides the others.

Is there a simple way to prevent that functionality to happen?

The visual style is the result of several css styles plus some JS dynamic manipulation of styles and properties that would be too hard to implement separately, that's why I'm looking for a way to use semtabs but without the switching feature.

It should look something like this:
[tabs http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/4029/picture1he.png](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/4029/picture1he.png)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to override the event handlers on the tabs so that they don't fire. That would prevent the tabs from switching.